# How to make json from array based on values in common

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hello I have a little problem I have arrays like this:

```
const arrays = {
    1: [c, u, g],
    2: [c, u],
    3: [c, u ,f],
    4: [c, g],
    5: [m, c, g],
    6: [u, m]
}
```

Values in each array are unique.
I would like to convert it to an object like this:

```
const object = {
  c: {
    u: {
      g: {
        ends: 1
      },
      f: {
        ends: 3
      }
      ends: 2
    },
    g: {
      m: {
        ends: 5
      }
      ends: 4
    }
  },
  u: {
    m: {
      ends: 6
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible ? And if so could you give me hint, piece of code or any other type of answer I'm hard stuck here.

Comment: Have you considered transforming the arrays to an object of wanted structure first and then converting that object to a JSON?

Comment: I did, but the problem is I need it to be properly sorted like shown in the example. The 'c' has to be obviously the most appeared value, then in the arrays with 'c' in them it has to look for new most appeared value in arrays with 'c' in them

Comment: Why is  `[m, c, g]` missing from the output?

Comment: i'm not sure I understand the reasoning behind your input and wanted output, like for example you have `m` in `g`, but `m` is before `c`.

You may have to loop 2 times, one first time to order by occurences  count ?

Comment: @adiga I think it became `c.g.m` it's also what is puzzling me

Comment: @kigiri I can be sorted alphabetically, but when I have for example array 'd,f,g', but you can still get 'a,b,g' and that is whats is making me problems.

Comment: Why didn't `[c,u,g]` become `[c,g,u]` in the output if the keys are sorted or `[u, m]` become `[m, u]`? Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the entries of the object. Then `reduce` each value array and create nested object in each iteration. The `reduce` returns the final nested object. So, add an `ends` property here.

If you don't want sorted nested path, you can skip the `sort` bit

```js
const input = {
  1: ["c", "u", "g"],
  2: ["c", "u"],
  3: ["c", "u", "f"],
  4: ["c", "g"],
  5: ["m", "c", "g"],
  6: ["u", "m"]
}

const output = {};

for (const [n, paths] of Object.entries(input)) {
  paths
    .sort()
    .reduce((acc, path) => (acc[path] = acc[path] || {}), output)
    .ends = +n
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you really much. I can make it work with this answer and a few tweaks. Thanks again! But if someone has the same problem this won't solve everything you still need to sort them by times it appears in all of the arrays.

Comment: @Xy77 Do you want to `sort` individual arrays based on how many times each of the strings appear in the overall object?